# Visual Studio 2017 - Compilação Condicional dependendo da arquitetura do servidor

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Queria uma ajuda sobre compilação condicional no visual studio, tenho uma biblioteca do SAP que utilizo no meus ambientes que preciso referenciar a versão correta desta DLL dependendo da arquitetura do servidor, por exemplo:

Tenho alguns web sites antigos que ainda estão hospedados em maquinas 32 bits, neste caso preciso compilar uma biblioteca que desenvolvi em 32bits para poder publicar em produção.

Já tenho outros sites mais novos que estão hospedados em outro servidor que a arquitetura é 64 bits, mas para poder utilizar a mesma biblioteca tenho que apontar para a versão das Dlls 64 bits e compilar.

Antes que digam algo, não resolve eu configurar o meu projeto para AnyCPU, não funciona.

O que gostaria de saber é se existe alguma forma de automatizar isso e evitar que eu tenha que toda vez que for compilar o projeto referenciar para a arquitetura correta, andei pesquisando e encontrei o link [inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://code-jedi.com/blog/post/Using-Platform-Specific-Libraries-from-a-Platform-Agnostic-Project) abaixo, mas não esta funcionando ele ignora as diretivas e sempre compila com as Dlls de 32 bits

[Exemplo Encontrado](http://code-jedi.com/blog/post/Using-Platform-Specific-Libraries-from-a-Platform-Agnostic-Project)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que `AnyCPU` não funciona?

Comment: Documentação da DLL, é uma dll da SAP o projeto em que ela for referenciada tem que ser 32 ou 64 bits... ja tentei com AnyCPU mas não rola...